# Riverpod: How to get ref in AsyncNotifier constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

[ApiRepository]

```
final apiRepository = Provider((ref) {
  Dio dio = ref.watch(appDioProvider);
  return ApiRepository(dio: dio);
});

class ApiRepository {
  final Dio dio;

  ApiRepository({required this.dio});

  late RestClient restClient = RestClient(dio);

  Future<ApiResult> fetchUsers({
    required int page,
    int perPage = 3,
  }) async {
    try {
      Pagination<UserModel> users = await restClient.getUsers(page: page, perPage: perPage);
      return ApiResult.success(users);
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      return ApiResult.failure(ApiError.getApiError(error), stackTrace);
    }
  }

  Future<ApiResult> fetchResources({
    required int page,
    int perPage = 3,
  }) async {
    try {
      Pagination<ResourceModel> resources = await restClient.getResources(page: page, perPage: perPage);
      return ApiResult.success(resources);
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      return ApiResult.failure(ApiError.getApiError(error), stackTrace);
    }
  }
}
```

[PaginationNotifier]

```
class PaginationNotifier<T> extends AsyncNotifier<Pagination<T>> {
  final Future<ApiResult<Pagination<T>>> Function(int) fetchNewData;

  PaginationNotifier({required this.fetchNewData});

  @override
  FutureOr<Pagination<T>> build() {
    state = AsyncLoading<Pagination<T>>();
    return fetchData().then((_) => state.value ?? const Pagination());
  }

  Future<void> fetchData({bool loadMore = false}) async {
    ApiResult<Pagination<T>> newData = await fetchNewData((state.value?.page ?? 0) + 1);

    newData.when(
      success: (value) {
        state = AsyncData<Pagination<T>>(
          value.copyWith(data: [if (loadMore) ...state.value?.data ?? [], ...value.data]),
        );
      },
      failure: (error, stackTrace) {
        state = AsyncError<Pagination<T>>(error, stackTrace).copyWithPrevious(state);
      },
    );
  }

  void loadMore() {
    if (state == AsyncLoading<Pagination<T>>().copyWithPrevious(state)) {
      return;
    }
    state == AsyncLoading<Pagination<T>>().copyWithPrevious(state);
    fetchData(loadMore: true);
  }
}
```

[UserNotifier]

```
final userProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider<UserNotifier, Pagination<UserModel>>(() {
  return UserNotifier();
});

class UserNotifier extends PaginationNotifier<UserModel> {
  UserNotifier() : super(
    fetchNewData: ref.watch(apiRepository).fetchUsers // The instance member 'ref' can't be accessed in an initializer error
  );
}
```

[ResourceNotifier]

```
final resourceProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider<ResourceNotifier, Pagination<ResourceModel>>(() {
  return ResourceNotifier();
});

class ResourceNotifier extends PaginationNotifier<ResourceModel> {
  ResourceNotifier() : super(
    fetchNewData: ref.watch(apiRepository).fetchResources // The instance member 'ref' can't be accessed in an initializer error
  );
}
```

I am trying to generate pagination API calls using Retrofit + Riverpod. Defined a Repository that calls the API and imported it as a Provider.

PaginationNotifier was created to be reusable, and Repository's function was designed to be received in the constructor.

In UserNotifier, ref object is required to obtain the Repository, but cannot access the ref object in the constructor.

Is there any good way?

Comment: What you're asking is not possible. You can't use ref in the constructor (and in fact shouldn't have a constructor on your Notifier).  You should do this in `build`

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thank you! I try of a way to implement it without using a constructor in Notifier..

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to get `ref` in constructor. Just change your classes to:

```dart
class PaginationNotifier<T> extends AsyncNotifier<Pagination<T>> {
  late final Future<ApiResult<Pagination<T>>> Function(int) fetchNewData;

  PaginationNotifier() {
    fetchNewData = ref.read(apiRepository).fetchUsers;
  }
  // ...
}

class UserNotifier extends PaginationNotifier<UserModel> {
  // No need of a constructor. 
}
```

Comment: Oh, I was lacking explanation.
Shouldn't call ApiRepository functions directly on PaginationNotifier for reusability.

Comment: `ref` can't be used inside the constructor.

Comment: @RémiRousselet With `StateNotifierProvider` you can pass a provider reference as a constructor parameter like: `StateNotifierProvider((ref) => UsersNotifier(ref.watch(usersRepository)))` and all functions inside the `UsersNotifier` had access to the repository (which doesn't change). Now with the `NotifierProvider`, how could I do the same if I can't use `ref` in the constructor and if I use it in the build I can lose the state if I'm watching another provider that if it changes? I should call the `UsersProvider` reference in each `UsersNotifier` function ? Thank you so munch!